# Missing return statement (Java): Calculating first 100 pentagonal number)

Tags: java

I  am  trying to   find the  first 100 pentagonal  numbers using methods. Below is my code, however, I keep getting missing return statement. I  sure  that  I  am not  placing  return  statement at the  appropriately, besides I wouldn't know if the  process is right. I would therefore appreciate guidance.  Thank  you.
PS: yet to  learn arrays and  this is no homework

```
public class PentagonNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberperline = 10;
        int n = 1;
        int count = 0;
        int pent = getpentagonnumber(n);
        count++;

        if (count % numberperline == 0)
            System.out.println();
        else System.out.print(pent + "\t");
    }

    public static int getpentagonnumber(int x) {
        for (int count = 0; count < 100; count++) {
            for (x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
                int result;
                result = x * (3 * x - 1) / 2;
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugly looking code.  Poor, inconsistent formatting detracts from understanding, makes your code hard to read, and encourages this kind of error.  I'd recommend paying more attention to formatting.  You're also going to get integer division problems in your result calculation.  This code is wrong.

Comment: If you want to get 100 numbers, you need to call a method that generate 1 number 100 times, or to call a method that return 100 numbers stored in a list or vector.

Comment: @duffymo.Thank  you  for  the formatting  comment. Can   you  clarify the "integer division problems".

Comment: Also, [homework or not homework is irrelevant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812).

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be changed like this:

```
public class PentagonNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberperline = 10;
        //int n = 1; // you do not need N
        //int count = 0; // you do not this either
        for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) { // moved
            int pent = getpentagonnumber(x+1); // +1 so it goes 1::100
            //count++;
            if (x % numberperline == 0)
                System.out.println();
            //else // you were skipping every tenth result.
            System.out.print(pent + "\t");
        }// close for
    }

    public static int getpentagonnumber(int x) {
        //for (int count = 0; count < 100; count++) { // moved
            //for (x = 1; x <= 100; x++) { // removed
                int result; // no need to declare and then calculate
                result = x * (3 * x - 1) / 2; // but not wrong either.
                return result;
            //}
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mindwin. It  should  be  (x+1) not  (n+1)

Answer (score -1):

You only have a return value inside a for loop. You probably meant for it to be:

```
public  static  int getpentagonnumber(int x ){
   int  result = 0;
   for (int count=0; count<100; count++){
        for (x=1;x<=100;x++){         
            result = x*(3*x-1)/2;
        }
   } //this was missing
   return result; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i just added the missing '}', but I changed it to what the original intent might be. Thanks!

Comment: That's not all; you need to initialize it as well ;)

Comment: @fge . thank   you   but the  outcome of  the code  is  wrong  after  making the  changes

Comment: @pumpin26 then this means there's a logic error in your code

Comment: @OriLentz this code returns the 100th number only... both `for` loops are useless. `int count` is not used anywhere, and the `for (x=1;x<=100;x++)` overwrites the `result` every iteration.